# placement of "exactly"

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, word-order

Which of these is correct?

> Could you tell me when the results will be posted **exactly**?
>
> Could you tell me when the results **exactly** will be posted?

Comment: Neither of your options is "wrong", but I think an even better option is: _Could you tell me **exactly** when the result will be posted?_

Comment: Neither sentence is perfect, Try. "_**Would** you please tell me exactly when the results will be posted?_". Note, you are asking for information so you should use "would". If you say "could" you are asking if it is possible to be told. A rude person might reply "I could, but I won't!"